# How to redirect using htaccess without causing a loop

Tags: .htaccess

I can't figure out how to redirect the URL below without causing a loop problem.  I would like to redirect this URL ...

http://toffsnew.co.uk/forum/recent

to this ...

http://toffsnew.co.uk/forum/recent?limitstart=0

using htaccess

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/forum/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(recent)/?$ $1?limitstart=0 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I've added it but it doesn't seem to be having any affect.

Comment: How did you test that it didn't have effect?

Comment: Well there is a problem with the forum menu and recent discussions.  This is supposed to be a fix for now.  If a user clicks on Recent Discussions and then goes off page one they can't return using the faulty URL.  They can only return to the page 1 results by the longer URL - http://toffsnew.co.uk/forum/recent?limitstart=0.  Adding your code isn't causing the desired redirect to occur.

Comment: But it still doesn't tell me how this rule is not working. To test further you can add `R` flag i.e. `RewriteRule ^(recent)/?$ $1?limitstart=0 [L,NC,R]` and then enter `http://toffsnew.co.uk/forum/recent` in browser to see if it becomes `http://toffsnew.co.uk/forum/recent?limitstart=0` or not

Comment: Still not seeing any movement.  My htaccess file looks like this ... http://toffsnew.co.uk/files/htaccess.txt

Comment: Oh my suggested rule should be places in `/forum/` folder's .htaccess

Comment: I was wondering about that.  There is no folder as such but I could create one and then test it - will try now.